# Blocking friendly minions

Tags: league-of-legends

Is it possible to effectively block friendly minions in League of Legends?

In the start of most DotA matches, players would block their minions to make the first battle take place closer to their own tower. I haven't seen anyone do this in LoL. I've tried a couple of times and failed.

Is it my lack of skill or just harder to pull off in LoL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in LoL. Anyways, you will certainly not be able to delay them long enough to be significantly closer to your own tower. However, you can easily let the minions fall back to your own tower, by not attacking the enemy minions (except for last hits).

As long as your lane opponents attack your minions, while you only last hit theirs, you will be at your own tower within one or two minion waves.

The worst possible case is if you're solo against two enemies. Then they will position themselves between you and your minions to drive you away, hence, you will not get any experience. In that case, there's not much you can do (if you engage at level 1, you normally die). However, the opponents will last-hit your minions, hence, pushing theirs. Again, they can only starve your XP for a wave or two, before everything is taking place in your tower's range.

(Note, however, that you usually don't want to fight in your tower's range all the time against ranged heroes. They will continually be able to hit your tower and eventually get it down.)

Answer (score 2):

The act of blocking is possible but the effect is soooo small that it's barely noticeable and has no real advantages. 
Even with a glitch like Annivia's wall (which is very hard to pull off btw with the creep's pathing) it's certain that you won't get them close enough to the tower.

And with the current metagame, at around that time you'd be better off scouting and hunting junglers with your team.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to the extent that you can do it in DotA/HoN. You can force vertical movement by moving WITH the creeps in their normal path, but nothing like "damming" the creeps behind you with move+stop commands. Additionally, it's not possible to neutral-pull like you can in DotA/HoN.

As briefly mentioned in Frank's post, the main reason behind doing this in DotA / HoN was to keep the creep wave closer to your friendly tower to make last hitting easier and making it next to impossible to get zoned early on. In LoL, the map is relatively smaller, and creep waves that get last-hit to death will quickly get pushed to the respective tower.

Focus on last hitting and neutral-creep killing if you're getting zoned/harassed (assuming your jungler doesn't need it). There's not really a point to trying to creepblock.

Answer (score 1):

It has been done with Heimer before (it is probably patched already)

It causes huge problems, as this video illustrates:

Comment: That video is very old -- the behavior has not been patched per se, but Heimerdinger only has 2 turrets these days, making such a block impossible.